# Java Swing - Multiple column headers in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any way to create multiple column headers in a `JTable`? I mean, normally there is only one row, but I need two of them with the same format (headerlike), and combine some cells of one of those headers.

I need something like this:

```
Header0 |          Header123          | Header4
Header0 | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 7):

Nick Meyer thanks for kindly reply, while the content in your address is a little out of date. i run it with jre 1.7 and it didn't works as expected but it can be altered to work correct.
the alter i made are as follow

```
/*
* add these code in GroupableTableHeader
*/

  public void updateUI(){
//      setUI(this.getUI());

      TableCellRenderer renderer = getDefaultRenderer();
      if (renderer instanceof Component) {
          SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI((Component)renderer);
      }
  }

/*
* add these code in GroupableTableHeaderUI in 2 places, you must know where
*/
      if (renderer == null) {
          renderer = header.getDefaultRenderer();
      }

/*
* change the getSize method in ColumnGroup 
*/

  public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, -1);
    int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height; 
    int width  = 0;
    Enumeration en = v.elements();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = en.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
        TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)obj;
        width += aColumn.getWidth();
//        width += margin;
      } else {
        width += ((ColumnGroup)obj).getSize(table).width;
      }
    }
    return new Dimension(width, height);
  }
```

and the finally results.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [Groupable Header](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm) example is some old code that might be able to help you.

Comment: I've used this before and really liked it.  worked like a charm

Comment: Link seems to be dead.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun, yes this is an old question. Did you try searching the web? I used "groupable header" and this is the first link that appeared: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can extend `BasicTableHeaderUI` and write your own implementation of paint method, in which you can draw any type of header.
after this change default header UI with following command `table.getTableHeader().setUI(MyTableHeaderUI)`